# Fsck at boot time for loopback device

Tags: fstab, fsck, loop-device

I discovered that is not possible to run `fsck` on a loopback device at boot by the `fsck` flag inside the `fstab` file, nor is it possible to accomplish this by manually running `fsck` when the loop device is mounted.

Is there an alternative to check the device at boot time?

Comment: doing it in a script?

Comment: Or as a service.

Comment: Fsck must runs before the loopback device mount. So putting it in a script (in /etc/rc.local for example) unfortunately is not suitable.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand with details; maybe showing the `/etc/fstab` you thought would work. It should work if the mount line includes the file system type, and the fsck pass is greater than the file system containing the loop-backed partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an elegant and reliable solution.

I have writteng a script for then"/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/" boot phase in order to process my loop disk just before the file system mounting.

Below the details:

1. Create the script into */etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/*.
2. Update the *initrd.img* by the command *update-initramfs -u*.

Here is the script source:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Antonio Petricca <antonio.petricca@gmail.com> - 03/01/2018

PREREQ=""

# Output pre-requisites
prereqs()
{
        echo "$PREREQ"
}

case "$1" in
    prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
        ;;
esac

. /scripts/functions

log_begin_msg "Running file system check on loop device(s)"

DEV=/dev/sdb5
MNT=/tmp/mnt
LOOP=$MNT/.linux-loops/242eef08-32d6-42c2-93eb-afdc2111a13e.ext4

mkdir $MNT && \
mount -t ntfs $DEV $MNT && \
fsck.ext4 -p -v $LOOP && \
umount $MNT

# Uncomment next line to hold messages for debugging
# sleep 10

log_end_msg "Done"

# Continue boot anyway

exit 0
```

Regards!

Comment: I have provided a more conveniente way by another post of mine (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421414/141129).

Answer (score 4):

The key phrase there is *"when the loop device is mounted"*.  You **can** run `fsck` on an unmounted loopback device.

In other words, you can run `losetup` to create the loopback block device and attach it the the relevant file, then run `fsck` on it, then `mount` it.

This, of course, can be scripted.  You could even do it in `/etc/rc.local` or similar if the loopback mounts were flagged `noauto` in `/etc/fstab` - then do the losetup/fsck/mount for each loopback fs in `/etc/fstab`.

Note that is kind of an abuse of the `noauto` flag because the loopback filesystem(s) will end up being automatically mounted.   Comment out any loopback filesystems that you don't want auto-mounted.

Alternatively, you could modify whatever code runs `mount -a` on your system (systemd, sysvinit shell script, or whatever) so that it runs `mount -a -tnoloop` instead, so that loopback filesystems are never automounted like other filesystems.  The script that does the losetup/fsck/mount could then be written to honour the `noauto` flag if present.

Comment: alternative is not possible for systemd, because that does not use `mount -a`.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, but I would give you other information about my setup. I have setup my loopback device inside fstab because I need (for some reasons) to override some system paths (/home, /var and /u01) before any service start. If I setup my loop device by the rc.local script it will be mounted after services startup loosing so integrity of my overridden file system.