# Persistent LVM device with loopback devices by fstab

Tags: lvm, loop-device

I like to create a LVM device where physical volumes are loopback devices.

I have read lot of documents and tutorials, like [this](http://www.anthonyldechiaro.com/blog/2010/12/19/lvm-loopback-how-to/). Unfortunately all of them are based on the *losetup* command, which loses its configuration at next reboot.

I would make the LVM settings using FSTAB in place of the RC.LOCAL (where the losetup maybe scripted) in order to get my LVM running before some services startup, but I don't know how to reproduce into the FSTAB the command: "losetup /dev/loop0 /opt/my-data-file-0" and so on...

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: You may use your startup system to sort starting order of services to make them start after your LVM  (I guess you use systemd ) example `Wants=applications.service
After=yourownLVMscript.service
`  ( if an fstab solution exists I m also interested )

Comment: @francoisP Maybe a solution, thank you very much! Further I should know if there is a way to implement the losetup command by the fstab setup, as stated in my post.

Comment: This is actually answered on another SE site: https://superuser.com/questions/799162/permanent-loop-device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a convenient way to do this: two SystemD services:

**/mnt/systemd/system/loops-setup.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Setup loopback devices

DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target

Requires=lvm2-lvmetad.service mnt-host.mount
Before=local-fs.target umount.target
After=lvm2-lvmetad.service mnt-host.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/losetup /dev/loop0 <LOOPBACK_FILE>
ExecStop=/sbin/losetup -d /dev/loop0

RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs-pre.target
```

**/mnt/systemd/system/loops-fsck.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Loopback devices filesystem check

DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target

Requires=loops-setup.service
Before=local-fs.target umount.target mnt-loops-loop0.mount
After=loops-setup.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/fsck -pfv /dev/loop0

Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs-pre.target
```

Comment: I get that: Aug 21 04:06:42 node-b losetup[1077]: losetup: /dev/loop0: failed to set up loop device: No such file or directory.. Any idea why ?

Comment: Please, post here the complete command you issued.

Comment: You probably don't need the latter unit file if you use fstab fsck column, like in e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/799162/permanent-loop-device